# How to make function variables defined by user?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, input

So I have code like this:

```
def hotel_cost(nights):
    return 140 * nights

def plane_ride_cost(city):
    if city == "Charlotte":
        return 183
    elif city == "Tampa":
        return 220
    elif city == "Pittsburgh":
        return 222
    elif city == "Los Angeles":
        return 475

def rental_car_cost(days):
    cost = 40 * days
    if days >= 7:
        cost -= 50
    elif days >= 3:
        cost -= 20
    return cost

def trip_cost(city, days, spending_money):
    return plane_ride_cost(city) + rental_car_cost(days) + hotel_cost(days) + spending_money

print (trip_cost("Tampa", 2, 200))
```

I know that I need to use input() to make all 4 variables (nights, city, days, spending_money) to be defined by user. But how exactly?

Comment: Take a look at the `input` function for a start :-)

Comment: I did it already. I put 4 'inputs' before every functions definition but I still don't know what to type at the end of code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for start:

```
a = input("Town:\n")
b = int(input("Days:\n"))
c = int(input("Money:\n"))

print (trip_cost(a, b, c))
```

Comment: That's the point. The last line solved my problem. Thanks a lot !